# How to implement GPUImage filters with chaining in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement custom filters with chaining GPUImage filters 
and I want change filter level using UISlider.
Anyone help to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sekhar always be precise while asking questions and elaborate your use case.

you can apply filters using --> operator.

chaining through filters instances.

**example**

colorFilter --> kuwaharaFilter --> dissolveBlend --> renderView

here colorfilter is some filter which I want to be applied firstly and renderview is the view on which output will come.

Follow the link for the solution.I asked this a year ago

**LINK** [How To Apply GPUImage filters efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151329/how-to-apply-gpuimage-filters-efficiently)

Comment: thank u
That operator not worked, I used another method